# Spearman correlations between Numpy array and every Pandas DataFrame row

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, pandas, scipy

I want to efficiently calculate Spearman correlations between a Numpy array and every Pandas `DataFrame` row:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import spearmanr

n_rows = 2500
cols = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(size=(n_rows, len(cols))), columns=cols)
v = np.random.random(size=len(cols))
corr, _ = zip(*df.apply(lambda x: spearmanr(x,v), axis=1))
corr = pd.Series(corr)
```

For now, the calculation time of `corr` is:

```
%timeit corr, _ = zip(*df.apply(lambda x: spearmanr(x,v), axis=1))
>> 1.26 s ± 5.19 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

I found [another good approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41806756/3679682) but it calculates only Pearson correlations:

```
%timeit df.corrwith(pd.Series(v, index=df.columns), axis=1)
>> 466 ms ± 1.12 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Is there a way to calculate Spearman correlations faster?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Spearman correlation is the Pearson correlation coefficient of the ranked version of the variables, it is possible to do the following:

1. Replace values in `df` rows with their ranks using `pandas.DataFrame.rank()` function.
2. Convert `v` to `pandas.Series`and use `pandas.Series.rank()` function to get ranks.
3. Use `pandas.corrwith()` function to calculate Spearman correlation - Pearson correlation on ranked data.

   ```
   import pandas as pd
   import numpy as np
   from scipy.stats import spearmanr

   n_rows = 2500
   cols = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']

   df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(size=(n_rows, len(cols))), columns=cols)
   v = np.random.random(size=len(cols))

   # original implementation
   corr, _ = zip(*df.apply(lambda x: spearmanr(x,v), axis=1))
   corr = pd.Series(corr)

   # modified implementation
   df1 = df.rank(axis=1)
   v1 = pd.Series(v, index=df.columns).rank()
   corr1 = df1.corrwith(v1, axis=1)
   ```

Calculation time of the modified version:

```
    %%timeit
    v1 = pd.Series(v, index=df.columns).rank()
    df1 = df.rank(axis=1)
    corr1 = df1.corrwith(v1,axis=1)
    >> 495 ms ± 13.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Checking `corr` and `corr1` for equality proves that the results are the same:

```
    print(corr.var()-corr1.var(), corr.mean()-corr1.mean(), corr.median()-corr1.median())
    >> (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
```